# Why kafka-avro-console-producer doesn't honour the default value for the field?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

Although default is defined for a field, `kafka-avro-console-producer` ignores it completely:

```
$ kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-avro \
--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 --property \
value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord1","fields": \
[{"name":"f1","type":"string"},{"name": "f2", "type": "int", "default": 0}]}'

{"f1": "value1"}

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error 
deserializing json {"f1": "value1"} to Avro of schema 
{"type":"record","name":"myrecord1","fields": 
[{"name":"f1","type":"string"},{"name":"f2","type":"int","default":0}]}
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected int. Got END_OBJECT
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.error(JsonDecoder.java:698)
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readInt(JsonDecoder.java:172)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ValidatingDecoder.readInt(ValidatingDecoder.java:83)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readInt(GenericDatumReader.java:511)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:182)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:230)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.jsonToAvro(AvroMessageReader.java:213)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readMessage(AvroMessageReader.java:180)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:54)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
```

How to use it then in order to accept the default? Top level config is set to  `"BACKWARD"` compatibility Level check, although I don't believe that has anything to do with the question. This schema is version 2, and version 1 was defined with only f1 field, but as I said, I don't think that matters.

Comment: AFAIK, the `default` value is only applicable to the reader/consumer. The field is still required to be defined by the writer/producer.

Comment: I already voted for this as a useful comment, if you promote it to answer, I will accept it as the one that solves the problem, and is the most useful.

Comment: @hdjur_jcv I believe that my answer explains how to do what cricket_007 has described.

Comment: Hi Giorgos Myrianthous, I have upvoted your answer as useful also, and I thank you for that, but I think that cricket_007's answer is the right one, because it reveals my misconception. Enabling null input value on producer side doesn't mean utilizing default zero value on consumer side (which should be the only my goal), as can be seen from your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined in the [Avro spec](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html)

> `default`: A default value for this field, used **when reading instances** that *lack* this field

Therefore, the producer still needs to supply that field.

I'm not sure it's possible to completely exclude a field when using the Avro console producer, because even if you make the field as nullable as Giorgos shows, you still need to explicitly set it.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the message is not compatible with the Avro schema you've defined. As far as I understand, you want to allow `null` values for field `f2`. To do so, you need to change your `value.schema` to (note the definition of `"type"`):

```
value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord1","fields": [{"name":"f1","type":"string"},{"name": "f2", "type": ["null", "int"], "default": 0}]}'
```

but you would still need to define `f2` key with null value. The following should do the trick for you:

```
kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-avro \ 
    --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \ 
    --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord1","fields": [{"name":"f1","type":"string"},{"name": "f2", "type": ["null", "int"], "default": 0}]}'

{"f1":"value1","f2":null}
```

And you can confirm that this has worked using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`:

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-avro --from-beginning
{"f1":"value1","f2":null}
^CProcessed a total of 1 messages
```